# Finding a limit or solving with a limit?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I have a complicated equation that has a lot of terms with squareroots.  I am simplifying that complicated function with assumption of that x << y , so that later I can use that solution to solve it for x.  Here is how the equation looks like approximately (just for illustration purpose):

$ f(x)=\sqrt{y^2 - (x + z)^2} + x*cos(\phi)+x+z$

My manual answer is:

$f(x)=\sqrt{y^2 - z^2} + x*cos(\phi)+x+z$

I tried in Mathematica but it does not solves it.   I am doing this limit to make f(x) simpler so that Mathematica can solve it for f(x)=0.

> Limit[f,x/y -> 0]

The limit does not work so I did not continue with solve. I also tried,

> Solve[f==0 && x/y->0,x]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this in a mathematically consistent manner you need to specify exactly what is the small parameter that you expand with. It seems from your question that you want to expand assuming the ratio $x/y$ is small. You can do that by defining `ϵ=x/y` and replacing that throughout your expression:

```
f  = Sqrt[y^2 - (x + z)^2] + x Cos[φ] + x + z
f2 = f/. x-> ϵ y
```

Then you can expand consistently to linear order in `ϵ`:

```
f3=Normal@Series[f2,{ϵ,0,1}]
```

and finally replace back to eliminate `ϵ`:

```
f4=Simplify[f3 /. ϵ -> x/y]
```

Note, however, that the result is different from your "manual" result, which is mathematically inconsistent.

Finally, you can solve using `Solve[f4==0,x]`.

Comment: @BobHanlon absolutely. A typo. Thanks

Comment: @BobHanlon (although in this particular case it makes no difference and it one can simply expand using `x` as the small parameter. I was just describing the general framework)

Comment: It makes a difference in that nothing is known about the relations between `x` snd `z` or `y` and `z`. The only given is `x << y` and it is implied that `0 < x << y`

Comment: Thanks yohbs I'll check the approach.

Comment: I run your method on my complicated equation.  When I did the part with Norma@series, the solution dependence on epsilon vanishes....In other words, function no longer have x variable in equations when I do ReplaceAll in f4 step. I am not sure if results are normal nevertheless your approach is correct.

Comment: The results rise another question : is it correct way to define x<<y (x is much greater than y)?

Comment: @Aschoolar This might simply mean that the equations don't have a **first order** term in `x`. If you want to look for all the terms up to 2nd order you can do `Normal@Series[f2,{ϵ,0,2}]`, for third order `Normal@Series[f2,{ϵ,0,3}]` and so on